# `echo 'main(){}' | clang-format -style='{BreakBeforeBraces: Allman}` not split?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang-format

Why doesn't this command produce a source code that has the line split before braces?

`echo 'main(){}' | clang-format -style='{BreakBeforeBraces: Allman}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a respone from `#llvm` IRC channel:

> jyknight $ because it fits in one line.
>   jyknight $ $ echo 'main(){foo(); bar();}' | clang-format
>   -style='{BreakBeforeBraces: Allman}'

Comment: See the AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine option in

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html